# Некоторые аспекты построения адаптера для RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

Здравствуйте! Уже как почти год пересел с `ListView` на `RecyclerView`. Собралось несколько вопросов - увидел много разных реализаций, понапридумывал своих костылей и хочется узнать про них подробнее.

**1. Не биндить в `onBindViewHolder`**

По сути этот метод и был для этого придуман, однако я все чаще замечаю метод `bind` в самом холдере. В `onBindViewHolder` в этот метод передавалась позиция.

**2. Не устанавливать слушатели в `onBindViewHolder`**

Я как только начинал, помню, ставил `onClickListener` и прочее на вьюхи в этом методе. Как я понял это плохо тем, что слушатель будет не один а столько же, сколько элементов в списке. Сейчас я всегда делаю по-другому: наследую холдер от нужного интерфейса слушателя (`OnClickListener`, например) в конструкторе холдера нахожу, например, кнопку и ставлю ей слушатель

```
item_delete.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Далее реализую метод `onClick` в холдере. Это хороший способ?

**3. Как работает `getAdapterPosition`?**

В подходе, описанном выше единственный способ получить позицию в холдере, в методе `onClick` - вызвать `getAdapterPosition`. Но.. Как он работает? Холдер знает о своей позиции? Значит не надо передавать в метод `bind` позицию?

**4. Как работает `notifyDataSetChanged`?**

Допустим я передаю какую-нибудь коллекцию, к примеру `List<String>`. В активности я что-то в нее добавил (или удалил), вызвал `notifyDataSetChanged` и список обновился. Неужели этот метод дергает конструктор адаптера? Будет ли этот метод работать если я изменю элемент коллекции? А если поменяю два элемента местами? И теперь самое интересное - а если передать коллекцию типа своей модели (поля, конструктор, геттеры, сеттеры), будет ли это также прекрасно работать? Например, после вызова какого-то сеттера.

**5. В чем отличия между `notifyDataSetChanged` и методами `notifyItem...`?**

Если первый дергает конструктор, то что делает второй? Вызывает `onBindViewHolder` определенного айтема?

Спасибо заранее за ответы :)

Comment: Чего-то мне кажется, что это все можно разбить на много вопросов, но не суть. По поводу "как работает", лучше пойти в исходники, вряд ли тут начнут расписывать и сделают это лучше, чем самому увидеть.